# Using RSpotify Gem and Spotify is including a query sting in URI which makes it an unapproved source, rails, heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, spotify

So I'm using the RSpotify to have users approve our app and then redirect to our site. The problem is that when Spotify redirects it is including a query string. This is throwing it off and it thinks that the URI is not an approved source.

Everything was working until I put my site up on heroku.

Here is the error:

```
    +00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-17T12:09:24.460751 #4]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2020-02-17T12:09:24.464829+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/spotify" host=www.themixtapeproj.com request_id=cf73be87-9844-4b18-ba0b-518e4046676a fwd="47.17.47.4" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=1463 protocol=http
2020-02-17T12:09:24.663083+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/spotify/callback?code=AQArRuRXYD_gebJVlU1Ljht_4XDFr_1dAAqlI-20Tq5504JFdP92MpRIDoNFVvBpS4xPPAqrdAJlooCTZA3yLPeUFKk5W1SE9KkLFsDp--1tIm2Vt2Y6_jrNWmDsBvWvBkuSlBbXaBW5gti8sbIHlMCHXt8MDP82l2BTduVDgjStbSuFt8SoWo8BLeYT8pc68LUs7eFqoJoww-ywkc0gLz1V7tzpEkOkn6I8N7-LRTr9cXQt_kJfQdnpsbiQ0KSn2g&state=2d5bbf3deccf88d92d68f5022475522564622cfc77104794" host=www.themixtapeproj.com request_id=f8ef1adc-0693-4ab5-bf63-f23b63b3ee1b fwd="47.17.47.4" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=50ms status=302 bytes=769 protocol=http
2020-02-17T12:09:24.612879+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-17T12:09:24.612791 #4]  INFO -- : [f8ef1adc-0693-4ab5-bf63-f23b63b3ee1b] Started GET "/auth/spotify/callback?code=AQArRuRXYD_gebJVlU1Ljht_4XDFr_1dAAqlI-20Tq5504JFdP92MpRIDoNFVvBpS4xPPAqrdAJlooCTZA3yLPeUFKk5W1SE9KkLFsDp--1tIm2Vt2Y6_jrNWmDsBvWvBkuSlBbXaBW5gti8sbIHlMCHXt8MDP82l2BTduVDgjStbSuFt8SoWo8BLeYT8pc68LUs7eFqoJoww-ywkc0gLz1V7tzpEkOkn6I8N7-LRTr9cXQt_kJfQdnpsbiQ0KSn2g&state=2d5bbf3deccf88d92d68f5022475522564622cfc77104794" for 47.17.47.4 at 2020-02-17 12:09:24 +0000
2020-02-17T12:09:24.613242+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-17T12:09:24.613191 #4]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Callback phase initiated.
2020-02-17T12:09:24.659971+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2020-02-17T12:09:24.659789 #4] ERROR -- omniauth: (spotify) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_grant: Invalid redirect URI
2020-02-17T12:09:24.659978+00:00 app[web.1]: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid redirect URI"}
2020-02-17T12:09:24.765658+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-17T12:09:24.765530 #4]  INFO -- : [bdbf5819-3907-42ba-9d02-6c32137425b5] Started GET "/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.themixtapeproj.com%2Fmixtapes%2F4&strategy=spotify" for 47.17.47.4 at 2020-02-17 12:09:24 +0000
2020-02-17T12:09:24.766489+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-02-17T12:09:24.766404 #4] FATAL -- : [bdbf5819-3907-42ba-9d02-6c32137425b5]
```

From what I understand it is the query string that is throwing it off. Since I have approved http://www.themixtapeproj.com/auth/spotify/callback

So what do I have to do to get this working?

EDIT: here is the authorize part (appears before the above error):

````
2020-02-17T15:41:52.150535+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/spotify" host=www.themixtapeproj.com request_id=2092bd50-787f-4f4f-a3a5-47e8ed29c171 fwd="100.38.116.113" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=302 bytes=1451 protocol=http
2020-02-17T15:41:52.032671+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/spotify" host=www.themixtapeproj.com request_id=43b76294-4e0b-4137-9c40-ef0d132d97ed fwd="100.38.116.113" dyno=web.1 connect=13ms service=66ms status=302 bytes=1457 protocol=http
2020-02-17T15:41:52.005375+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-17T15:41:52.005256 #4]  INFO -- : [43b76294-4e0b-4137-9c40-ef0d132d97ed] Started GET "/auth/spotify" for 100.38.116.113 at 2020-02-17 15:41:52 +0000
2020-02-17T15:41:52.005965+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-17T15:41:52.005846 #4]  INFO -- omniauth: (spotify) Request phase initiated.
2020-02-17T15:41:52.140507+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-17T15:41:52.140388 #4]  INFO -- : [2092bd50-787f-4f4f-a3a5-47e8ed29c171] Started GET "/auth/spotify" for 100.38.116.113 at 2020-02-17 15:41:52 +0000 ```
````

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
        spotify_key = ENV['SPOTIFY_KEY']
        spotify_secret = ENV['SPOTIFY_SECRET']
        provider :spotify, spotify_key, spotify_secret, scope: 'playlist-modify-public'
end
```

```
def spotify
    spotify_user = RSpotify::User.new(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    session[:spotify_user] = spotify_user.to_hash
    redirect_to spotify_landing_path
```

end

Comment: "The URI to redirect to after the user grants or denies permission. This URI needs to have been entered in the Redirect URI whitelist that you specified when you registered your application. The value of redirect_uri here must exactly match one of the values you entered when you registered your application, including upper or lowercase, terminating slashes, and such." https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

Comment: What is the query in the callback URI being used for? The question does not really show the actual call to `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize...` that starts the whole chain so its hard to figure out what you are trying to do. You can get it from the network tab in firebug/web inspector.

Comment: max I've entered the redirect URI into the whitelist. Unfortunately, that's not what they are trying to go to now. (I've already got this working on my local server but it doesn't work now that I moved to heroku.) I will show you the authorize part of the chain.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but the most vital information which is the redirect to `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize...` is missing. You won't find it in the logs.

Comment: Well I don't exactly know where you mean. I'm using RSpotify which uses Omniauth.

Comment: I added some more info. I will reformat all this as soon as I can.

Comment: This may not fix it but use `ENV.fetch('SPOTIFY_KEY')` as it will raise an error if the key is missing and fail fast. I don't know how much debugging time this has saved me over the years.